# How to make a flex responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am using flex so that the two inner div(s) height remains the same. But problem that I am facing is that, the design is not responsive. In full width window it looks perfect but when we view it in a mobile device it tries to squeeze the content.

How to solve this issue?

Is there any other way to give the height same for the two div(s) side by side? (The data is dynamic, so i cannot set a height property for any of the div(s))

My fiddle link : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yc92u1g2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=yc92u1g2)

```css
.image-bg-fluid-height {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 51px 0 0 0;
}

.image-bg-fluid-height,
.image-bg-fixed-height {
  /*text-align: center;*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.gradient-background {
  background: #00BCD4;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #00BCD4);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #00BCD4);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #00BCD4);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #00BCD4);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

.icon.default-bg {
  background-color: white;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.default-bg {
  background-color: #09afdf;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 58px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.default-bg {
  background-color: #09afdf;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.feature-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.tech-button {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #00ACC1;
  border-color: #00ACC1;
}

.tech-button:hover {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.tech-button:active {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.tech-button:target {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.tech-button:focus {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.box-title {
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.web-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 5px;*/
  /*-moz-border-radius: 5px;*/
  /*border-radius: 40px;*/
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.signup-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #00BCD4;
}

.text-color {
  color: white;
}

.tld-span {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(14% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(14% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.tld-span > a {
  color: white;
}

.tld-span > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.manual-label {
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.export-button {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #00ACC1 !important;
  border-color: #00ACC1 !important;
}

.export-button:hover {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.export-button:active {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.export-button:target {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.export-button:focus {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 30 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="image-bg-fluid-height" style="display: flex;">
            <div class="col-md-8 gradient-background">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-3 feature-box">
                        <span class="icon default-bg"><img src="/logos/favicon.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin-top: 25px;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-6 col-sm-3 feature-box text-color">
                        <h6>TECHNOLOGY</h6>
                        <h3>Tech</h3>
                        <p>Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream Loream .</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pull-right">
                <span class="tld-span pull-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#export-modal" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Export</a>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="flex: 1;">
                    <div class="col-md-12 feature-box text-center">
                        <p>Count</p>
                                                <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px #BDBDBD;">
                        <p>Top websites</p>
                        <a href="#top-websites" class="btn btn-default tech-button">VIEW WEBSITES</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </header>
```

Note: The top black part is the padding for my header.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not good to mess CSS stylesheet with inline attribute style, however, since you are taking advantage of bootstrap, you could make it responsive with a simple `class="col-md-8 col-xs-12"` which means takes 8/12 columns in medium screen and 12/12 columns in screen that is below medium.

But since your `display: flex;` is blocking the elements take the percentage width by bootstrap, so you may have to use the media query `@media (min-width: 992px)` which is the default media query of the medium view of bootstrap

`@media (min-width: 992px) { .image-bg-fluid-height { display: flex; } }`

```
<header class="image-bg-fluid-height">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 gradient-background">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #FAFAFA;">...</div>
</header>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/yc92u1g2/1/